Нужно ли ставить запятую в сложноподчинённых предложениях такого типа?
Как вообще поступать в таких случаях(,) мы не знали, но старались сделать всё возможное.
Объясните, пожалуйста.

Можно поставить запятую:
Как вообще поступать в таких случаях, / мы не знАли, // но старались сделать всё возмОжное.
Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, в главном предложении однородные сказуемые: мы не знали, но старались.
После придаточного нет подчеркнутой паузы, которая обозначалась бы тире. Основная пауза делается перед союзом НО.

Авторский вопрос: Нужно ли ставить запятую?.. Ваш ответ: Можно поставить запятую... То есть по смыслу ответа получается, что можно запятую и не ставить. А это неверно. [Нужно, считаю редактировать,]

Редактировать ответ я не буду, но дополнительные пояснения дам.

Дополнительное пояснение по комментарию
Имеется в виду следующее: можно поставить запятую, а не тире, как это было до этого предложено.
Грамматика предложения представляется интересной.
(1) Формально это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным в препозиции.  И для этого случая у Розенталя предлагается тире как возможный знак:
  Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части 
  СПП от придаточной. Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех 
  случаях, когда главной части предшествует: 1) придаточная 
  изъяснительная: Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не 
  мог он понять (Г.); Как рассказывал учитель — долго слушал 
  у окна я (Пл.).

(2) Однако в заданном предложении  грамматическая основа включает однородные сказуемые, при этом придаточное  относится к одному из них. Поэтому, как я думаю, в названии вопроса упоминаются "сложноподчинённые предложения такого типа".
Соответственно, по семантике  просматривается трехчастная конструкция: Как вообще поступать в таких случаях, / мы не знАли, // но (мы) старались сделать всё возмОжное.
При этом  основная пауза делается  перед союзом НО, и тогда в предыдущей части не должно быть сильного знака (тире) с его подчеркнутой паузой. Этим объясняется постановка запятой, а не тире.

Мне кажется, что здесь нет условий, благоприятствующих постановке тире. Достаточно просто запятой.

Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если стоит внутри главной части; если же придаточная часть стоит перед главной частью или после нее, то отделяется от нее запятой...

Как вообще поступать в таких случаях, мы не знали, но старались сделать всё возможное (придаточная часть предшествует главной).
Мне очень хотелось обнять его, но я чувствовал, что парень близок к истерике. А как успокаивать в таких случаях, я не знал (К. Бэд. Дурак космического масштаба).
Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении (ПАС)
